# Как заменить сразу несколько символов на разные значения в строке (java)

Tags: java, строки

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class zamena {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите ваш текст на английском: ");
        String a = scn.nextLine();
        String n = a.replace('q', 'й');
        String n1 = a.replace('w', 'ц');
        System.out.println("Вывод: ");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
String n = a.replace('q', 'й').replace('w', 'ц');
System.out.println("Вывод: " + n);
```

Comment: Спасибо, Но я имел ввиду замену нескольких символов

Comment: Спасибо, заработало

Comment: @СашаСамчук Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.